# Add timestamp to file name in org export

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

How can I create a time stamped file name with the org header arg:

`#+export_file_name: <timestamp-var> + File name`

There is a variable `org-time-stamp`, is there a way to append it to the static file name to create files with time stamp at time of export in the file name?

Thanks

Comment: There is no such variable AFAIK. There is a *function* named `org-time-stamp` but that's a different kettle of fish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your init file:

```
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'time-stamp)
```

and this to the Org file:

```
# Local Variables:
# time-stamp-format: "%04y-%02m-%02d_%f"
# time-stamp-pattern: "^#\\+export_file_name: %%$"
# End:
```

The value of `#+export_file_name:` should update every time the file is saved.

Comment: Thanks! Doesn't work for me, not sure why!

Comment: Make sure you (1) add the variables at the end of the file, and (2) kill and reopen the file (or `M-x normal-mode`) to set them. You also have to add `#+export_file_name: nil` near the top of the file (and start with some initial value or it won't work).

Comment: Thanks, that worked. More details on the formatting on the emacs wiki [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TimeStamp) and the time format in the emacs docs [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Parsing.html). `%f` is the variable for the file name.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like

```
(org-export-to-file 'pdf (concat "success_" (format-time-string #%FT%H:%M:%S") ".pdf"))
```

is close to right.  The call to concat seems to work, but the call to org-export-to-file doesn't.

Even if I had made this work, I'm not sure how to insert it so that it's run automatically by the exporter.

Help?